# How bind array parameters in find request?

Tags: php, arrays, bind, phalcon

I want to add conditions to my request based on the permissions of the logged in user

I try this :

```
$t = array();
$t[] = 3;
$statements = Statement::find(
            [
                'conditions' => 'societe_id IN (?1)',
                'bind' => [
                    1 => $t
                ],
                'order' => 'date_reception DESC'
            ]
        );
```

The error is :

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
```

I use PaginatorModel with the resulta

I found no documentation about bind array parameters.

have you a solution ?

Thanks

Comment: maybe you wrong bind parameters? Did you try like in this doc example? https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/db-models#binding-parameters (3rd code)

Comment: Thanks @JanuszO. it works ! I am on Phalcon 3.4 but it works

Answer (score 0):

The answer (thanks @JanuszO) :

```
$statements = Statement::find(
            [
                'conditions' => 'societe_id IN ({societeId:array})',
                'bind' => [
                    'societeId' => $t
                ],
                'order' => 'date_reception DESC'
            ]
        );
```